# How to creat sticky bar?

Tags: templating, html-entities

I have new project, but have one issue . And someone help me to code the sticky bar as Menu - Social share...

I use wordpress template. Thanks

Comment: Doesn’t seem like this has anything to do with Craft CMS. I’d recommend to ask this on Stack Overflow (if it’s a general JavaScript question).

Comment: please read [ask]

Answer (score 2):

using jQuery you can do this like this

```
var num = 200; //number of pixels before modifying styles

$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('.menu').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('.menu').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

Code Demo [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luckmattos/yp8HK/1/)